# How to parallel a for loop with pthread in iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to parallel a simple for loop with pthread. All it needs to do is to access a global array by different thread.

```
    for(int i = 0, i < ary.count; i++){
    //do something with ary[i];
    }
```

How to do that?

Comment: Apparently you didn't try anything.

Comment: Do you want this loop on separate thread, or each iteration on separate thread? If latter, see [`dispatch_apply`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_apply) or [Performing Loops Concurrently](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW23) or WWDC 2011 video [Blocks and Grand Central Dispatch in Practice](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=308).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` to enumerate the elements of the array using multiple threads:

```
[ary enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerationConcurrent usingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
    // do something with object
}];
```